# How do I preserve generic type information when accessing a Stateful Flutter Widget property from the Widget State?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, statefulwidget

I've got a simplified example below.  In practice, I'm passing a list of data objects to a StatefulWidget.  I want the Widget to copy the provided list into its state object which will then be filtered through future interactions.  The filters use a type parameter so they know what fields they can work with in a callback, for example `Filter<MyData>`.

So, I'm trying to create a Widget that is aware of the `MyData` type so it can build the FilterChip Widgets using MyData fields.  I tried to achieve this by adding a type parameter to both the StatefulWidget and its State class.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Generic type information loss example
class MyWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<T> things;
  const MyWidget({Key? key, required this.things}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState<T>();
}

class _MyWidgetState<T> extends State<MyWidget> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<T> things = widget.things; // Compiler error (IDE shows widget.things has a type of List<dynamic>)
    return Container();
  }
}
```

This code results in:

> `Error: A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<T>'.`

So what I don't understand is, why does `things` in the `StatefulWidget` class have a type of `List<T>`, but when referenced through the `widget` property of the class extending`State<MyWidget>`, `widget.things` has a type of `List<dynamic>`.

And, as a result, any code in the state class that needs to be aware of the type now breaks.  At runtime, the filter callbacks result in errors like:

> `type '(MyData) => bool' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool'`

Comment: I'll leave this question open since it provides a different set of keywords to get to the other answer. (I searched for hours and read dozens of SO posts without finding it.)

While the phrasing is a little different the linked answer pointed out what I had overlooked.  The type parameter was on the body of the `createState()` method, but not the return type.  Even more importantly, while I had the type parameter on the State class, it was missing from the extension.

`class _MyWidgetState<T> extends State<MyWidget>`
to
`class _MyWidgetState<T> extends State<MyWidget<T>>`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is only `class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget`, without `<T>`.

Then you don‘t need to copy your list to preserve the list. Just use `widget.things`, this is considered best practice. The data remains during the rebuilds.

Comment: It is possible to write a generic implementation of a StatefulWidget, after reviewing the linked answer, what was missing was the type parameter in two additional places.

This article walks through a generic implementation in more detail: https://mobikul.com/generic-type-widget-in-flutter/